# How to change windows blink cursor shape from c++?

Tags: windows, cursor, blink

How to change windows blink cursor shape from vertical which is by default ( | ) to horizontal like that used in dos ( _ ).

Is there some good function that take care about that?

OS: win7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually called a *caret*, rather than a *cursor*. That's probably where the confusion comes from, and why searching for a solution didn't yield very much of use. [NullPonyPointer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439717/how-to-change-windows-blink-cursor-shape-from-c#comment18373963_13439717) reflects this common confusion as well. The `SetCursor` function is indeed what you would want to change the mouse cursor, but it won't work to change the caret.

Fortunately, there is a whole group of Windows functions that work with carets: [`CreateCaret`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648399.aspx), [`ShowCaret`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648406.aspx), [`HideCaret`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648403.aspx), [`SetCaretPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648405.aspx), and [`DestroyCaret`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648400.aspx). There are some others for manipulating blink time, but I recommend sticking to the user's current settings (which will be the default).

First, a bit of background. I strongly recommend reading the two introductory MSDN articles [about carets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648397.aspx) and on [using carets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648398.aspx). But here's a quick summary: The caret is owned by a window; in particular, the window that currently has the focus. This window will likely be something like a text box control. When the window receives the focus, it creates a caret to use, and then when it loses the focus, it destroys its caret. Obviously, if you don't do any of this manually, you will receive the default implementation.

Now, the sample code. Because I like candy machine interfaces, I'd wrap it in a function:

```
bool CreateCustomCaret(HWND hWnd, int width, int height, int x, int y)
{
    // Create the caret for the control receiving the focus.
    if (!CreateCaret(hWnd,    /* handle to the window that will own the caret */
                     NULL,    /* create a solid caret using specified size    */
                     width,   /* width of caret, in logical units             */
                     height)) /* height of caret, in logical units            */
        return false;

    // Set the position of the caret in the window.
    if (!SetCaretPos(x, y))
        return false;

    // Show the caret. It will begin flashing automatically.
    if (!ShowCaret(hWnd))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Then, in response to [`WM_SETFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283.aspx), [`EN_SETFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761685.aspx), or a similar notification, I would call the `CreateCustomCaret` function. And in response to [`WM_KILLFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282.aspx), [`EN_KILLFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761682.aspx), or another similar notification, I would call `DestroyCaret()`.

Alternatively, `CreateCustomCaret` could have created the caret from a bitmap. I might provide the following overload:

```
bool CreateCustomCaret(HWND hWnd, HBITMAP hbmp, int x, int y)
{
    // Create the caret for the control receiving the focus.
    if (!CreateCaret(hWnd,   /* handle to the window that will own the caret   */
                     hBmp,   /* create a caret using specified bitmap          */
                     0, 0))  /* width and height parameters ignored for bitmap */
        return false;

    // Set the position of the caret in the window.
    if (!SetCaretPos(x, y))
        return false;

    // Show the caret. It will begin flashing automatically.
    if (!ShowCaret(hWnd))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey Cody, really many thanks for effort, this post is old and i almost forget about it, with think that changing caret is staff that take too much investigation, and i didn't find much good information on internet, but you show me the other side! Thnx man you are awesome, i really appreciate it!

Comment: @tonni Sure! You said yesterday that I'd helped you before. I didn't remember that, but it got me looking at some of your old questions in your profile, and I saw that this one was unanswered. You're right, there's not much info on this around online. It's not something people do very much anymore. Changing the cursor was much more popular back in 1992 with 16-bit Windows. The original books on the Windows API devoted a chapter to carets, but you don't see that anymore. Good info to have available.

Comment: "You said yesterday that I'd helped you before. I didn't remember that" - heh yes you help me and i remember that, but i have some other account for which i lose password, but know for shore that is help came from you :)

Comment: @tonni you can request the other account getting merged into your current account or vice versa at http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge.