# how to use a textbox but having an underscore line and blinking cursor?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created Windows forms and I'm using the textbox control for input, but I like to use it without border and other layout for textbox etc.  I just want to use a underscore line and blinking cursor.

I played with the borderStyle (Fixed3D, None), backcolor=InactiveBorder etc. But I still do net get the underline... like this-> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***  result like this:  This is underline_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

I think Backcolor=InactiveBorder and BorderStyle=None is ok to use, but how to get the **underline** and blinking cursor?

Requirement:

- blinking cursor and underline.   (The doesn't blink by default, I just see a vertical line))

Answer (score 1):

To fake this, you could add a label below the text box with the content being `_____________________`. My preferred solution would be to create a simple custom control that just draws a line.

Doesn't the caret on your system blink by default? It does on my system if the focus is on the text box.

If the caret doesn't blink by default, go to the Windows Control Panel and check your Keyboard Settings there - this is the place where you can adjust the caret blink rate.

Comment: no it's not blinking by default, I updated my question regarding this too. btw: I'm newbie with winforms, so I could be struggling with the code with drawing a line.

Comment: Well, then use a `Label` as I suggested - even though this is really bad fake :-) About the blinking cursor: Windows itself is responsible for the caret to blink. This is not something you need to "switch on" in your code. You can, however, change the shape of the caret as described in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439717/how-to-change-windows-blink-cursor-shape-from-c. However, by default in Windows the caret is a vertical line that blinks. If it doesn't, check the keyboard settings in the Windows Control Panel. There you can adjust the cursor blink rate.

Comment: The problem with using a Label control instead of a TextBox is that you have to write all of the text input code yourself, which is not going to be simple. And even once you get something written that appears to work, it'll be rather fragile and lacking a number of features (e.g., IME support). It's much simpler to use a TextBox with all of the complex logic built in and just skip drawing the borders, etc. that you don't want.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant! I meant to put a borderless textbox on the form, and align a label with it below. The text is entered in the text box as usual, the label contains many `_` to simulate the underline.

Answer (score 1):

For creating a `underline` for your `textbox` you can do like this,

- First add a `panel` which is in the height of **text box's height + underline's height**.
- Now add your `textbox` inside of that `panel` and set its `dock` to `TOP`.
- Then set the textbox's `border` to `none`.
- Now set the `backcolor` of the `panel`, according to the color need of underline.

---

### Update:

### *This is VB code, i hope that you can easily convert it into c#*

[ **Concept:** You just need to set the border for all of your textboxes as none.then In forms paint event track those text boxes and draw a line under it. ]

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    Using xPen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Blue)
        ' Here we are using LINQ to filter the controls.
        ' If you don't want it, you just check all the controls by using typeof
        ' inside the For Each loop.
        For Each xTxtBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(xPen,
                                xTxtBox.Location.X,
                                xTxtBox.Location.Y + xTxtBox.Height,
                                xTxtBox.Location.X + xTxtBox.Width,
                                xTxtBox.Location.Y + xTxtBox.Height)
        Next
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: sounds good, looks like easy to, but I have 3 forms and approx. 20 textboxes per form. so I need to create then per textbox a panel... that's a lot of maintenance for me... but it's simple and creative solution and much work :(... thanks for the answer

Comment: Oh.. its ok, cool. I just added an update, check that out, it'll definitely suits your requirement.

Comment: I fixed your code. You should *never* dispose of the automatically-provided `Graphics` object inside of a `Paint` event handler. And there's no reason in having an empty try/catch block just to use the finally block. It's much cleaner to use a `Using` statement to manage disposal of the `Pen` object and anything else you create.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, i just learned a new concept `USING` Because of you. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use Masked TextBox and set Focus , e.g. `maskedtextbox1.Focus();` <== this is for the blinking cursor and the masked textbox to the underline !

try :

> To set logical focus to an input control
>
> ```
> FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, textboxJack);
> ```
>
> To set keyboard focus to an input control
>
> ```
> Keyboard.Focus(textboxJill);
> ```

and for the masked textbox you can set a mask that will not be changed when you delete the text from it not like the simple textbox  :)
Good luck

Comment: I've used maskedTextbox control and set the focus() on OnLoad, but it's still not blinking... and do not see the difference with Textbox. how to do the underline in Maskedtextbox?

Comment: @mesut see answer changes :)

Comment: I don't have problem with focus, it's the underline. so there is no underline.

Comment: thanks Obama. this is above my knowledge, I thought something like simple 2-3 lines of code or a property.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I would recommend creating a custom control (which is accomplished in the WinForms world by inheriting from one of the provided control classes). That custom control would then:

1. Provide its own drawing logic (by overriding `OnPaint`) in order to draw the underline and skip drawing anything else you don't want to see (e.g., the borders of the control).
2. Create its own caret when it receives the focus, and destroy that caret when it loses the focus. You'll find all the details on how to do this [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15800591/366904).

You can also configure the blink rate of the caret by calling the [`SetCaretBlinkTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648404.aspx) function. But note that this is *not recommended*, as it changes the global system setting and therefore affects other applications. It is best to do as [Thorsten suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15807681/366904) and modify the setting on your machine if you wish to see something different. You should always respect a user's settings. There's a reason that they (or someone else) set up their system to not blink the caret.

Naturally, you will need to use P/Invoke to call these Win32 API functions related to caret management from a C# application. That shouldn't be too difficult if you know what you're doing. If you need a complete solution, consider [setting a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on this question to persuade me to write one up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and built something that works fine:

```
public class TextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
    public TextBox()
    {
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        Text = "__________"; //Sometime this doesn't work while creating the control in design mode ; don't know why
    }

    //protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    base.OnFontChanged(e);
    //    RefreshHeight();
    //}

    bool loaded = false;
    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        if(!loaded)
            RefreshHeight();
        base.OnCreateControl();
    }

    private void RefreshHeight()
    {
        loaded = true;
        Multiline = true;
        Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, Font, Size.Empty, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
        MinimumSize = new Size(0, s.Height + 1);
        Multiline = false;
    }
}
```

I used `bool loaded = false` to avoid the app to crash in a loop because of `OnCreateControl`. **TextBox** control doesn't have `OnLoad` event (I'm open to another approach).

`OnFontChanged` can be uncommented if your app change the font size in run time

`MinimumSize = new Size(0, s.Height + 1);` **I added 1** to avoid any error of `MeasureText`